# Liquid: How to assign the output of an operator to a variable?

Tags: operators, variable-assignment, liquid, assign, assignment-operator

I'm working with Liquid templates for Shopify. I want some elements to show up only if the month happens to be December. Since there are multiple elements that need this, I want to set a variable at the top of the document and refer to it later. Here's what I've got that's working:

```
<!-- At the top of the page -->
{% assign month = 'now' | date: "%m" %}
{% if month == "12" %}
{% assign isDecember = true %}
{% else %}
{% assign isDecember = false %}
{% endif %}

<!-- Only show in December -->
{% if isDecember %}
Happy Holidays
{% endif %}
```

This works (for testing I change "12" to the current month) but it is pretty ugly. In most languages I would do something like this:

```
{% assign isDecember = (month == "12") %}
```

Liquid doesn't accept parentheses, so obviously this won't work. And it doesn't work without parentheses either. The documentation has examples for [using operators](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/operators/) and for [assigning static values to variables](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/variable/), but nothing about combining the two.

I can assign the output of a `|` filter to a variable, but there don't seem to be filters to cover every operator (or even the necessary "=="), so that's unsatisfactory.

Is there any way to assign the output of an operator to a variable in Liquid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way to do that elegantly and according to [this](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/236), they won't support ternary operators. There's a mention of someone trying a similar thing.

A slightly shorter/different version would be:

```
{% assign month = 'now' | date: "%m" %}
{% liquid
case month
when '12'
  assign isDecember = true
else
  assign isDecember = false
endcase %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could altogether avoid using an intermediary boolean flag variable `isDecember` as Liquid `assign` with only boolean variables seems to not working within `if/endif`. Here are the solutions.

1. Just use plain strings:

```
{% assign month = 'now' | date: "%m" %}

{% if month == "12" %}
  Happy Holidays
{% endif %}
```

2. Or use plain string assignments (not boolean values assignments) within `if`s:

```
{% if month == "12" %}
  {% assign phrase = "Happy Holidays" %}
{% else %}
  {% assign phrase = "Happy usual time of the year" %}
{% endif %}

Now my message to you is: {{ phrase }}
```

3. Still want unsing intermediary `isDecember`? If you would put some dummy text assignment within either clause of `if/else` that would work too.

```
{% if month == "12" %}
  {% assign dummy = "summy" %}
  {% assign isDecember = true %}
{% else %}
  {% assign isDecember = false %}
{% endif %}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: inner `assign` does not honor outer condition. so it's always rendered to the last `assign`